# Radio button disabled due to css from template

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

my radio buttons seem to be disabled due to a css file.
The css was provided by a template. How I know that the issue is due to the css file is because when I commented out the reference to the css file, my buttons are working fine. But I need the css file to make my web page look nicer.
I have tried commenting out the css styling for radio buttons however to no avail.

I have attached a screenshot of my radio buttons, the jquery on how i created it, as well as the css code provided by the template. 
[image]

```js
for( answers in allQuestions[i].answer){ //loops through array and dynamically adds answer values to radio buttons
  var radioBtn = $('<input type="radio" class="radios" name="btnAnswers" value="'+ allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '" /><label for ="secondbtn">' 
                   + allQuestions[i].answer[j] + '</label><br>');
        radioBtn.appendTo('#radios');
     j++
 }
```

**Below is the css related to radio inputs**

```css
input[type="checkbox"] + label,
input[type="radio"] + label {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #777;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 1em;
  font-weight: 300;
  padding-left: 2.55em;
  padding-right: 0.75em;
  position: relative;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  font-family: FontAwesome;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: none !important;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before,
input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  background: #f8f8f8;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: solid 1px #e5e5e5;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1.8em;
  left: 0;
  line-height: 1.725em;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  top: 0;
  width: 1.8em;
}

input[type="checkbox"]:checked + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:checked + label:before {
  background: #666;
  border-color: #666;
  color: #ffffff;
  content: "\f00c";
}

input[type="checkbox"]:focus + label:before,
input[type="radio"]:focus + label:before {
  border-color: #e89980;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px #e89980;
}

input[type="checkbox"] + label:before {
  border-radius: 6px;
}

input[type="radio"] + label:before {
  border-radius: 100%;
}
```

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Comment: can we see the live example or codepen something?

Comment: @Aman 
Hi here you go: https://codepen.io/asterzwx/pen/zbjabp
I don't know why it will take some time for the Start Quiz button to be clickable to start the quiz, so just wait a moment while it loads and you can test the radio buttons

Answer (score 0):

You are not using `id` on input element, As `for` in `label` should be associate with respective `input` element with the help of `id`.